# User input loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, user-input

I can't get this short piece of code to work. What I am trying to do is ask user to enter a 4 letter word, if they don't then ask them to try again, if they do then to say thanks. I added the while True, try & except part as it looked like the best way to keep looping around but I didn't really get it.

```
while True:
    try:
        word=input("Please enter a four letter word: ")
        word_length=len(word)
    except word_length != 4:
        print("That's not a four letter word. Try again: ")
        continue
    else: 
        break

if word_length ==4:
    print("Thanks")
```

Comment: You could start by identifying what language you are trying to use.

Comment: Sorry using python 3

Comment: not sure why my code hasn't displayed correctly in my question sorry

Comment: What is your exact question or problem?

Comment: That's not how you use `except`.  You use `except` to catch an exception thrown by something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`except` is for catching exceptions (other languages use `try` and `catch` instead).

In this case, you just need to use a simple `if` to check if the value is what you want:

```
while True:
    try:
        word = input("Please enter a four letter word: ")
        word_length = len(word)
    except TypeError:
        print('error getting word length')
    else:
        if word_length != 4:
            print("That's not a four letter word. Try again: ")
        else:
            break

if word_length == 4:
    print("Thanks")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help - the bit that's missing is the loop back around, so it says try again but doesn't allow user to input for a 2nd time when I test this?

Comment: @EleanorLaurence Yes, looks like I needed to move the `word_length` check into the `else` of the `try` block.

Answer (score 1):

Use `if-else` instead of `try-except`:

```py
while True:
    word=input("Please enter a four letter word: ")

    if len(word) == 4:
        print("Thanks")
        break
    else:
        print("That's not a four letter word. Try again: ")
```